# Tenderizing vegetables (chili pepper)

Tags: vegetables, chili-peppers, hamburgers, tenderizing

I am trying to emulate a hamburger recipe I ate at a restaurant with some green chili pepper (Chile Verde) which I really enjoyed.

My problem relies on how to cook it, if I just use the pan it burns or does not reach the soft consistency I am looking for.

Is there any way I can easily tenderize the chili pepper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roast in a hot oven, over grill or direct flame, or in cast iron. Whole...until skin is dark and blistered. Remove from heat carefully.  Place in a bowl and cover with plastic.  Allow to cool.  The peppers will continue to steam as they cool.  Wipe off skin. Then de-seed and dice.  They will be tender.

Comment: This work perfectly. I know it was sort of basic but thanks for your time and knowledge.